# How to write a custom assert message for an assertion on a single value in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

In pytest you can register a hook to provide a custom assertion message via:

```py
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(config, left, right, op):
    if isinstance(left, Foo) and isinstance(right, Foo):
        return ["Assert failed because Foo!"]
```

This only runs for tests of the form:

```py
assert Foo() == Foo()
assert 5 is 6
assert "char" in "mychar"
assert 10 > 20
```

and so on. It does not run for single operand expressions:

```py
assert Foo()
assert ProduceValue()
```

Is it possible to write a hook that displays a custom assertion message if assert is called with a particular value? I don't need this to happen for all values, just when a particular class is evaluated. If there's an alternative way to "fail" a test with a custom assertion, that would work too.

Comment: What if you just make instances of the class always evaluate as False in a boolean context?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but the objects are complex and I'd like more information to be provided in the pytest failures than just "False, expected True"

Comment: How about first explicitly asserting that the objects aren't instances of Foo?

Comment: Why do you need `assert Foo()`? Why not something more explicit like `assert Foo().attribute == 'expected_value'`?

Comment: The use case is an alternative to https://github.com/syrusakbary/snapshottest. I'm interested in supporting the syntax `assert snapshot(value)` rather than `snapshot.assert_match(value)`. I currently have `snapshot(value)` resolving to false if the snapshot doesn't match, however I would like to print out the snapshot differences. If this isn't possible, I may fallback to the `snapshot.assert_match` route, however I think the alternative syntax reads nicer with pytest.

Comment: Looks like this feature is not supported at this moment.

Comment: Is it possible via an assert rewrite? I've been having trouble finding examples

Comment: Assertion rewrites won't help you here. You can abuse exception handling and implement custom [`pytest_exception_interact`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact), check whether `call.excinfo` is an `AssertionError` and has a matching message. You won't get access to the asserted object though; you'll need to store it in some global context elsewhere. Change the error message via e.g. `report.longrepr = 'my custom error desc'` in the hookimpl, or look up how pytest nodes implement their `repr_failure` methods.

Comment: I managed to replicate much of the existing pytest assertion behaviour via parsing traceback and printing via pytest.fail. Traceback only includes the assertion line, so if I want to get the few lines before and after, I'll likely have to read the source.

Comment: That looks like a useful hook though, thanks.